# How can I prevent someone modifying properties in a Javascript object?

Tags: javascript, object, closures

Given an object like :

```
var eventEmitter =function  (){
  this.listeners = 0;
  this.events = {};
  return this;
};
```

Assuming it's someone's goal to maliciously reassign any property they can in the object, how can I prevent someone from taking what I've written and reassigning `this.listeners` to something arbitrary?

I know I can use getters and setters but they would just be able to reassign the `this.get` method. Also, I know I can use object descriptors to make the properties not writable, but what about when I need to modify the listener count, for example?

Comment: Assuming this is client-side JS, there's nothing you can do to stop anyone to modify the code on their own computer. (And why would they want to? It's their own computer they're "hacking".)

Comment: @JJJ I feel one could make a distinction between preventing and stopping. Some would argue, for instance, obscuring ones production code is a preventative measure. Also, the idea of targeted attacks or cheats against a site via something like Chrome addons content scripts are not unheard of. So there could be people subject to a hack, even if the code is tampered with client side.

Comment: If there is someone executing potentially malicious code in the same environment, you're basically out of luck. Don't even try to limit them, prevent them from getting access in the first place.